# How can I make a constructor of a Java record private?

Tags: java, java-record

By creating a Java record

```
public record Rec(String foo, int bar) {}
```

[one also gets a](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/records.html)

> public constructor whose signature is derived from the record components list

One can refine the behavior of this constructor by the so called compact constructor

```
public record Rec(String foo, int bar) {
    public Rec { /* ... */ }
}
```

What does not work, though, is making the constructor private.

```
public record Rec(String foo, int bar) {
    private Rec { }
}
```

> java: invalid canonical constructor in record Rec
> (attempting to assign stronger access privileges; was public)

Is there any way to make the constructor of a record private?

*In case someone is thinking why one would do such a thing. The record should be extended with a builder. To enforce using the builder the constructor should be private.*